# How to update me endpoint in Strapi?

Tags: content-management-system, strapi, headless-cms

Im working with Strapi v3.4.0 for a project. I want to allow the authenticated user to update his personal informations when hitting the following endpoint:

```
PUT /users/me
```

for now I'm just trying to console.log a message when i hit the endpoint, I have followed the step from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITk-pYtOCnQ but I keep getting 403 error "Forbidden". Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I understand this update me problem in Strapi is really painful. I have also followed the tutorial on the link you put above to no avail since Strapi just updated to the new version. I tried a workaround for this solution. So basically, I tried to create an additional method on the model that shows on the api folder (Previously, I am trying to add a new method on user controller but again I got this 403 error as well). As for my approach, I created a model called User Profile and then add the custom method for updating the current user data shown below.

> api/user-profile/config/routes.json

```
...
{
  "method": "PUT",
  "path": "/updateMe",
  "handler": "user-profile.updateMe",
  "config": {
    "policies": []
  }
},
{
  "method": "PUT",
  "path": "/user-profiles/:id",
  "handler": "user-profile.update",
  "config": {
    "policies": []
  }
}
...
```

and on the controller, I added the following snippets

> api/user-profile/controllers/user-profile.js

```
'use strict';

 const _ = require('lodash');
 const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');
 
 const sanitizeUser = user =>
   sanitizeEntity(user, {
     model: strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').model,
   });
 
 const formatError = error => [
   { messages: [{ id: error.id, message: error.message, field: error.field }] },
 ];
 

module.exports = {
    async updateMe(ctx) {
        const { id } = ctx.state.user;

        let updateData = {
            ...ctx.request.body,
        };

        const data = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.edit({ id }, updateData);

        ctx.send(sanitizeUser(data));
    },
};
```

After that, enable the updateMe for the public use (for now, you do not have to worry since the `ctx.state.user` line will check if the token is valid or not, { at least until the developer officially create this updateMe function })

That is all. You just have to pass the attributes to the body and the auth header and you are good to go. You can pretty much put the function anywhere you want

PS: Take a note that you have to put the updateMe route above the update route. Else, it will give you the same 403 error

PPS: This is just a workaround until the developer officially includes the updateMe function, which we cannot expect in short time